# Python, empty array shows error and ruins the code, trying to fix

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

Function works well with dictionaries and shows needed result, however if there is empty array, then it shows error.
How can I just add the line to the output,that if there is missing array, then it shows:
"no data"

The code:

```
data = [
  {
    "firstname" : "Peter",
    "lastname"  : "Doe",
    "class"       : [ "economy_class" ]
  },
  {
    "firstname" : "Jane",
    "lastname"  : "Braun",
    "class"       : [ "business_class" ]
  },
  {
    "firstname" : "Peter",
    "lastname"  : "Foo",
    "class"       : [ "business_class", "economy_class" ]
  },
  {
    "firstname" : "Jane",
    "lastname"  : "Bar",
    "class"       : [ "business_class" ]
  },
  {
    "firstname" : " ",
    "lastname"  : " ",
    "class"       : [ " " ]
  }
]

def list_persons(data):
    """Returns a string that contains the list of persons for each affiliation.
    Persons and affiliations should be separated with a newline character '\n'.

    Arguments:
    persons -- list of dictionaries with persons and affiliations
    """
    # YOUR CODE HERE
    class_set = set()
    for dic in data:
        for i in dic['class']:
            class_set.add(i)
    for i in sorted(list(class_set)):
        subjects = [dic for dic in sorted(data, key=lambda d:d['lastname']) if i in dic["class"]]
        names = ', '.join(sorted([f"{dic['firstname']} {dic['lastname']}" for dic in subjects], key=lambda x: x[5]))
        print(f"{i}: {names}")
```

Or I think it would be better, in situations, when there is missing data just for 1 type of data: "lastname" for example, we see "NO DATA".

Comment: What do you want to sort on ? Because the error is dure to empty names, not empty class

Comment: What is your expected output? Should the `" "` class be printed? With what names?

Comment: I was thinking, that if database has empty fields. For example We have "Firstname" but we dont have "Lastanme", then there should be not empty output, but "NO DATA.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of empty firstname+lastname, with couldn't be indexed at 5.

Remove the second layer of sorting, and with some smiplification, here you go

```
for i in sorted(class_set):
    subjects = sorted([dic for dic in data if i in dic["class"]], key=lambda d: d['lastname'])
    names = ', '.join(f"{dic['firstname']} {dic['lastname']}" for dic in subjects)
    print(f"{i}: {names}")
```